# How to execute promises "sync" and not in async way

Tags: angularjs, promise, q

I calling getBubblesUserAccess that returns json objects that are orderd in a special way. This results i wanna run a foreach and get other messages but there i wanna return them in "order". I know that it will run these async but there must be a way that i can force it to "sequential" execution. (above code is my last attempt to add a defer...)

**Example**
*pseudo code* - get my groups

```
{  
  "id":"016cd1fc-89a3-4e4a-9e6e-a102df1b03d9",
  "parent":"53750396-7d26-41f3-913d-1b93276b9e09",
  "name":"XX",
  "createdBy":"c9c63080-2c5b-4e8e-a093-2cfcd628a9d0",
  "hasWriteAccess":true,
  "hasCreateAccess":false,
  "hasDeleteAccess":false,
  "hasAdminAccess":false,
  "settingsBubbleId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
},
{  
  "id":"016cd1fc-89a3-4e4a-9e6e-a102df1b03d9",
  "parent":"53750396-7d26-41f3-913d-1b93276b9e09",
  "name":"XX",
  "createdBy":"c9c63080-2c5b-4e8e-a093-2cfcd628a9d0",
  "hasWriteAccess":true,
  "hasCreateAccess":false,
  "hasDeleteAccess":false,
  "hasAdminAccess":false,
  "settingsBubbleId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
}
```

From this result i wanna iterate over those parent id strings and call another service that respond with this.

*pseudo code*
for each group above call another service with parent id and get result. This result will be added to a new JSON object.

```
"messages":[  
  {  
     "id":"f1d1aeda-d4e2-4563-85d5-d954c335b31c",
     "text":"asd",
     "sent":"2015-09-10T22:31:09.897+00:00",
     "sender":"6b9e404b-ef37-4d07-9267-3e7b2579003b",
     "senderName":"XXX XXXX"
  },
  {  
     "id":"a7ac0432-e945-440e-91ce-185170cbf3de",
     "text":"asd",
     "sent":"2015-09-10T22:28:24.383+00:00",
     "sender":"c9c63080-2c5b-4e8e-a093-2cfcd628a9d0",
     "senderName":"ZZZZZ ZZZZ"
  },
```

My problem is that my second foreach are running async (as it should) and i want it to resolve back in same order as first json object...

My code::

```
var loadBubblesAccess = function () {
        if (vm.running && angular.isDefined(vm.running)) { return; }
        vm.running = true;
        vm.bubblesWithMessages = null;

        return BubbleFactory.getBubblesUserAccess().then(function (bubblesAccessTo) {
            return bubblesAccessTo;
        });
    },
        loadSubBubbles = function (bubblesAccessTo) {

            /**
             * Result from chain method with all bubbles user has access to.
             */

            var promiseArray = [];
            //var promiseArrayError = [];
            var i = 0;
            /**
             * Creates a defer object so that we will not resolve before for each loop has been gone thru.. async problems.
             */
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            angular.forEach(bubblesAccessTo, function (bubble) {
                $log.error(JSON.stringify(bubblesAccessTo));
                /**
                 * Get 20 because default thats default and cache and e-tags are done to that number..
                 */
                BubbleFactory.getBubbleMessages(bubble.id, 0, 20, false).then(function (data) {
                        i++;
                        if (data.messages.length > 0) {
                            promiseArray.push({ bubbleSortOrder: i, bubbleId: bubble.parent, bubbleName: bubble.name, bubbleMessagesId: bubble.id, bubbleMessages: smartTrim(data.messages[0].text, 400, ' ', ' ...'), bubbleMessagesSent: data.messages[0].sent });
                        }
                        else {
                            // console.log("YYYY::: " + bubble.parent);
                            promiseArray.push({ bubbleSortOrder:i, bubbleId: bubble.parent, bubbleName: bubble.name, bubbleMessagesId: bubble.id, bubbleMessages: 'Inget meddelande än..', bubbleMessagesSent: '' });
                        }

                    });

                    /**
                     * Check if we have gone thru all bubbles - when finished we resolve defer object.
                     */
                    if(i===bubblesAccessTo.length)
                    {
                        deferred.resolve(promiseArray);
                    }

            });
            //$log.debug.log(promiseArray);
            vm.bubblesWithMessages = promiseArray;
            promiseArray.length = 0;
            vm.running = false;
        };



    loadBubblesAccess().then(loadSubBubbles);
```

Comment: If you made an array of promises and then used `$q.all()`, the results should be in the correct order in the `.then()` of `$q.all`

Comment: I tried that approach with looping foreach and att them to promiseArray and then execute them in q$.all but same result. :(

Are you sure it will execute them in right order with q.all?

Comment: The individual callbacks will always be out of order, you'll have to get the data from the single callback of .all()

Comment: You can use `[].reduce` to go through them in order and wait for one to complete before calling the next. Check out the "Collection Kerfuffle" section in this article: http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/

Comment: @MrWeiland: You don't care about the order in which they are executed, you only care about the order of the results in the array, right? `$q.all` is the way to go. Please show us your attempt at using it.

Comment: I get back - i trying again with $q.all functionallity...

Comment: I think i should use .spread - i call each function and get back results and then i will combine results into one json array that will be sent to controller. Because one of the things is that with $q.all i get results back but i want to have information from first results also.. I will be trying this approach when i come home..

`q.all([loadSomething(), loadAnotherThing()])
 .spread(function(something, another) {
  DoSomethingOnThem(something, another);
});`

Comment: @MrWeiland: That looks good, except that `$q` (Angular promise, not Q!) doesn't have a `spread` method. just use `.then(function(results) { DoSomethingOnThem(results[0], results[1]); })`. Or do you actually use Q (as you tagged)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$q` service in AngularJS is described as "lightweight" because it only implements the functions 90% of people need. That keeps its code size small - at the expense of not being able to address requests like yours very easily.

If you have the option, try an alternative such as `bluebird`. Bluebird provides a `reduce()` function that can execute an array of promises serially, and return their results in the order they were requested. It makes this task straightforward because your result array will match your data array and you can match up the results very easily.

If you do NOT have that option, there is a standard (if not-exactly-simple) technique with promises where you build an array of the elements you want to promise, then call the processing function (that returns a Promise) on the first value (popped from the array). In the `.finally()` handler, call the processing function recursively with the next value until it is empty (or an error occurs).

Pseudo-code for this:

```
var valuesToProcess = [1, 2, 3],
    results = [];

function processValue(val) {
    myProcessingFunction(val).then(function(result) {
        results.push(result);
    }).catch(function(e) {
        console.log('FAIL!', e);
    }).finally(function() {
        if (valuesToProcess.length > 0) {
            processValue(valuesToProcess.shift());
        } else {
            // All done - do something with results here
        }
    });
}

// Note: No error checking done, assumes we have work to do...
processValue(valuesToProcess.shift());
```

You'll need to adapt this to your use-case but it's a simple technique that guarantees serial operation and result-handling.

Comment: I needed in the end to fix it in backend API because my solution for this was alots of array manipulating in front-end and i dont like this code to be messy.. :( I guess @chad-robinson and kevin-b your answer would have done it. But i really dont like todo alots of array processing :(

Comment: But i guess this isnt last time i will have this problem - i will bookmark and go back if i have similar problem in future. :)